# Spring Integration: individual timeouts settings for connections in the same pool

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, tcp, connection-timeout

We've got an application written in Java that uses Spring Integration. The application sends requests to 3d-party service, each request is represented as byte array and is sent via plain TCP. Connections to the 3d-party are stored in a pool (CachingClientConnectionFactory is used).

There are several types of requests that we can send to the 3d-party, and now there is a need to have different timeout values for each type of requests. However, right now this looks problematic, as far as connection timeout settings are set for Gateway and ConnectionFactory components, and there is no way to setup connection timeout for a particular single request.

We would like to avoid introducing multiple gateways and connection factories just to support different connection timeouts.

**Channel & Gateway configuration**

```
<int:channel id="myInput" />

<int:gateway id="myGateway" 
    service-interface="com.mypackage.TcpGateway"
    default-request-channel="myInput"/>

<int-ip:tcp-outbound-gateway id="myOutGateway"
    request-channel="mybInput"
    reply-channel="clientBytesChannel"
    connection-factory="myConnectionFactory"
    request-timeout="${conn.timeout}"
    remote-timeout="${conn.timeout}"/>
```

**TcpGateway.java**

```
package com.mypackage.TcpGateway;

public interface TcpGateway {
    byte[] send(byte[] message);
}
```

**RequestProcessor.java**

```
public class RequestProcessors {
    @Autowired
    private TcpGateway myGateway;

    public MyResponse process(MyRequest requestMessage) {
        byte[] binaryMessage = transformRequest(requestMessage);
        byte[] response = myGateway.send(binaryMessage);
        return transformResponse(response);
    }

    // rest of business logic here
}
```

Looking at the source code above, it seems that the simplest way could be to extend native component TcpOutboundGateway and replace property `remoteTimeout` with a singleton bean that holds timeout settings as a `ThreadLocal` variable. Then it will be possible to set necessary value based on the request type in `RequestProcessors.process()` method just before the request is passed to `myGateway.send()`.

However, I was not able to find an elegant way to redefine TcpOutboundGateway component using my custom class. After analyzing source code of Spring Integration, it seems that TcpOutboundGateway doesn't know anything about input request, but is registered in a chain of message processors and is called whenever it is required. So, right now this doesn't look like a simple solution.

If you have any ideas how to change the class that is used by tag `<int-ip:tcp-outbound-gateway>`, or if you have any ideas how the main timeout problem could be resolved in a completely different way, please advise.

Thank you.

Comment: Is it possible for you to post your solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting problem.

You are correct that (currently) the `AsyncReply` object has no knowledge of the original outbound message.

One thing we could do is add a `remote-timeout-expression` and calculate the timeout based on the message...

`AsyncReply reply = new AsyncReply(calculateReplyTimeout(requestMessage));`

Feel free to open a [JIRA Improvement Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT).

In the meantime if you want to customize the gateway, you can easily do so.

While the namespace (`<int-ip:...`) doesn't support custom classes, you can always wire up the gateway with `<bean/>`s.

You need a `ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean` and it gets your custom gateway in its `handler` property.

Comment: I think we can use an existing issue on the matter https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3635

Comment: Thanks Gary! I was waiting for your response :)
Probably I didn't get complete understanding of your idea. I believe when we define a `TcpOutboundGateway` component using the `<bean/>` tag, it is not possible to specify an input channel, as far as gateway is not aware about it (and doesn't have correspondent property). How can `ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean` help with this?

Comment: Outbound endpoints consist of 2 components, a consumer endpoint and a message handler; the tcp gateway is the message handler; the `ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean` builds the right kind of consumer, based on the input channel type. Certain properties are on the `CEFB`  (`inputChannel` `autoStartup`, `handler` etc); the remaining properties (e.g. `connectionFactory`) are on the handler. The namespace parser hides this (minor) complexity.

Comment: Works perfectly, Gary! Appreciate your help!